# How to set up development server for Mattermost

Tags: docker, go, window, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mattermost

https://developers.mattermost.com/contribute/server/developer-setup/

I tried to follow along the instructions for Window/WSL set up

According to the instruction:

**"If you are using 1803 or higher, then you need to create a file /etc/wsl.conf"**

I've checked my version is higher than 1803

**Edit**: Version 2004 [OS Build 19041.746]

When I run  `wsl -l -v`
I see this:

```
   NAME                   STATE           VERSION
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
  Ubuntu-18.04           Stopped         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
```

**But I'm not sure which directory I should create this file /etc/wsl.conf**
(e.g. in Local Disks? Users ? ...)

Also, at step #6:

"Update your shell’s initialization script (e.g. .bashrc or .zshrc) and add the following"

**But I don't see any .bashrc file. Where should I find this file or create this file**

It might be a silly question for you, but I'll greatly appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction or suggest any resources/ tutorial links!

THANK YOU!!!!!  :))))

Comment: could you put the exactly windows version?

Comment: I guest that you need to install a linux distro, you can follow this tutorial if it is not too invasive  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10